# How to inject a service into Behat feature context in Slim 4 framework

Tags: bdd, slim, behat, slim-4

When I search for service injection to feature context I always find extensions for symfony. But I need extension or something else to do this in Slim 4 framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a trait.

```php
    // src/Application/Utility/ContainerInjection.php

    use DI\Container;
    use DI\ContainerBuilder;

    trait ContainerInjection
    {
        /**
         * @return Container
         */
        public function getContainer()
        {
            // To find project base path 
            // according to path where trait is found
            $path_main = __DIR__ . '/../../../';

            // Instantiate PHP-DI ContainerBuilder
            $containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

            $settings = require $path_main . 'app/settings.php';
            $dependencies = require $path_main . 'app/dependencies.php';

            $settings($containerBuilder);
            $dependencies($containerBuilder);

            // Build PHP-DI Container instance
            return $containerBuilder->build();
        }
    }
```

To use this trait in FeatureContext

```php
    class FeatureContext implements Context
    {
        use ContainerInjection;

        private $myService;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $container = $this->getContainer();
            $this->myService = $container->get(MyService::class);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Have you been able to run REST tests *without* doing actual HTTP requests, but running internal Request/Response in Slim4?